# one sql query for multiple conditions in the filter

Tags: sql, mysql

hey i need a query where there is a filter that comes from html.
example

> `<input = name="location" value="">`
> `<input = name="gender" value="">`
> `<input = name="level" value="">`

if location has a value and else is null i want the return from query like

> `SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE location = value_location`

if only value level is empty then i want return from query

> `SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE location = value_location AND gender = value_gender`

the question is whether it is possible with only 1 query for various conditions or do you have to use if else on the backend for several different conditions.

i use CI3 php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM db_user 
WHERE (value_location IS NULL OR location = value_location)
  AND (value_gender IS NULL OR gender = value_gender)
```